# Designing a near real time streaming backend

Tags: solr, streaming, nosql

I have the following requirements for designing a streaming backend :

1. Documents are getting added  @ 20 docs/sec. Each doc has a timestamp field.
2. Searches are primarily based on timestamp range ( e.g. show me documents arrived in last 20 minutes )
3. Search QueriesPerSecond : 100 searches/sec
4. Documents older than 2 days could be continuously deleted for optimization purposes ( by a cron )

I am thinking of using Solr ( with SolrReplication/NRT ). The problem with Solr is basically frequent updates/deletes. For freshest data I will need to do commit on each update ( otherwise data wont be visible by searchers). Setting pollInterval~1 minute might kill the master/server both. NRT/SolrCloud could be one fo the options, but not very sure about their stability.

Any other approaches/suggestions based on SQL/NoSQL architectures ?

Comment: If search is primarily on timestamps, why use Solr, which is primarily a full-text search engine?

Comment: Solr was just one of the options I thought of with the potential advantage of providing you a search feature at a later point of time. Are you suggesting mysql ?

Comment: What I'm saying is that any database, relational or not, can run common queries, but Solr is intended to be used as a *full-text* search engine. So if you won't do full-text queries, you'll probably want to choose a different database.

Answer (score 0):

mysql + memcached. Facebook runs their entire site on these two widely-available, widely supported, free and open source packages.

Comment: Not sure memcached will help as every new query will have new timestamp_range. Any idea on what is the latency of mysql's slaves getting updated with master's values ? I want it to be < 60 secs.

Comment: @PrasenjitMukherjee Assuming both servers on the same LAN, with minimal latency, you can expect less than one second for master-slave replication updates.